# Uploading Retina Images to Google Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

I would like to upload retina versions of my Google Adwords display ads (at twice the size) for my campaign, is this possible, and if so, how/where do I upload the retina-sized files?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to upload banners twice a size for retina displays into AdWords interface without any problems. AdWords itself decides, when to serve retina/standard verison.

*List Of Retina Sizes: as of 08/2014:*

```
Banner - 936 x 120 
Inline Rectangle - 600 x 500
Leaderboard - 1456 x 180
Mobile Banner - 640 x 100
```

Sources:

- [Digital Information World](http://www.digitalinformationworld.com/2014/04/retina-display-ads-epic-smartphone-targeting-techniques.html)
- [AdWords](https://www.en.adwords-community.com/t5/Advanced-Features/How-to-serve-only-interstitial-banners-in-mobile-apps-campaigns/td-p/388819)

Answer (score 0):

List Of Retina Sizes:
Banner - 936 x 120
Inline Rectangle - 600 x 500
Leaderboard - 1456 x 180
Mobile Banner - 640 x 100  
**and**
**672 x 560

320 x 1200**

Uploaded today (09/2016). Used the adwords interface and not the adwords editor.